# JavaFX: can't call a Controller function from anoher class

Tags: function, class, javafx, controller

I have this simple controller:

```
@FXML
private VBox VVbox;

private ButtonBar newNode = new ButtonBar();
private Circle c= new Circle();
private Button b= new Button();
private Label lname = new Label();
private Label lIMEI = new Label();
private Label lroot = new Label();


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void create(String imei){
    System.out.println(imei);
    newNode = new ButtonBar();
    b = setButtonSpec(imei + "btnHavefun");
    c = setCircleSpec(imei + "statuOnline");
    lname= setLNameSpec(imei + "name");
    lIMEI = setLIMEISpec(imei + "Imei");
    lroot = setLrootSpec(imei + "root");
    newNode.getButtons().addAll(lname,lIMEI,lroot,b,c);
    VVbox.getChildren().addAll(newNode) ;
}
```

this is my main:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Thypheon Application");
    Connection connessione = new Connection();
    Thread t = new Thread(connessione);
    initDesign();
    t.start();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void initDesign(){
    try {
        loader2= new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Design.fxml"));
        AnchorPane anchor  = (AnchorPane) loader2.load();
        rootLayout.setCenter(anchor);
        controller = loader2.getController();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see in main I start a new thread in which I would like a Controller function.

```
public class Connection implements Runnable {
String result;
Controller controller = new Controller();
public void run() {
    controller.create("TEST123");
}
```

Everything seems to be inside create function until The last line is executed: VVbox.getChildren().addAll(newNode) ;
Probably because it has a reference to the FXML file.. How can I solve this?

Comment: For the general concept of communicating with a controller see [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml). In your specific case you create a new controller you create a new controller that has none of it's fields injected, since it's not used with `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: Oh i will try this.. I will check better that post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right. The controller that you instantiate yourself does not get its fields injected by `FXML`. To obtain a reference to the controller the following is a possible solution:

```
public Controller initDesign(){
    // some FXML loading code
    return controller;
}
```

You will then need to modify your `Connection` to take a `Controller` object in the constructor:

```
class Connection ... {
   Controller contoller;
   public Connection(Controller controller) {
       this.controller = controller;
   }
}
```

Finally in `start()` you will need:

```
Controller controller = initDesign();
Connection connessione = new Connection(controller);
Thread t = new Thread(connessione);
t.start();
```

However, there is more than one issue with your design.
Your `Connection` instance is NOT run on `JavaFX Application Thread`. Therefore, any attempt to modify the scene graph from a different thread (e.g. your call to `VVbox.getChildren().addAll(newNode);`) will cause an error.

The `start()` method is called from JavaFX Thread. There is no need to create a new thread. I am unsure of the intentions, but you can call your `create()` from `Controller` in `start()` to be executed on JavaFX Thread.

Comment: Thank you so much  for the clarify.. i will check it and I will set your answer as best as soon as possible. 
Just a little question how can I implement A JAVAFX Thread.. is it different from normale thread?

Comment: The start() method is called from JavaFX Thread. There is no need to create a new thread. I am unsure of the intentions, but you can call your create() from Controller in start() to be executed on JavaFX Thread.

Comment: Ok man I simply created the class inside the MainApp thread and everything worked.. So pratically I ve made what you adviced me in the comment above. If you update the answer with that.. I can check it as Solved.